# How to combine ICU Collation customize Rules

Tags: mysql, sorting, sqlite, icu

I want to use two ICU Customize Collation  rules in my  application like :

1. "&b < a"
2. "&z < w"

So , how to combine these rules , so that I can use it in ucol_openRules() API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate them. See [Adding user defined rule to existing language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057922/adding-user-defined-rule-to-existing-language)